# How to reformat XML with related element groups using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, transformation

I'm improving some XML I have inherited by using XSLT to clean things up, but I'm struggling with one section. Which looks like this:

```
    <rules>
        <if condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="1"/>
        <elseif condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="2"/>
        <elseif condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="3"/>
        <else/>
        <if condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="4"/>
        <else/>
    </rules>
```

This looks to be difficult to validate with XSD, so I'd like to transform it into something like this -- ideas?

```
    <rules>
        <conditionSet>
            <if condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="1"/>
            <elseif condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="2"/>
            <elseif condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="3"/>
            <else/>
        </conditionSet>
        <conditionSet>
            <if condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="4"/>
            <else/>
        </conditionSet>
    </rules>
```

Answer (score 1):

Group `elseif` and `else` elements by their immediately preceding `if` element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="block" match="elseif|else" 
             use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::if[1])"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="rules">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|
                    node()[not(self::elseif or self::else)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="if">
        <conditionSet>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('block', generate-id())"/>
        </conditionSet>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This stylesheet produces the requested output.

**Explanation:** The `xsl:key` associates each `if` element with its following, related elements, so that, later, when we match an `if`, we can simply wrap and copy the entire set.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting XSLT challenge.  But, uh, why are you changing the XML again?  The pattern in the input can easily be defined by a regular expression, namely

```
(if, elseif*, else)*
```

and for that reason it is easy to validate with XSD.

It may be worth while to change -- a veteran vocabulary designer (Lynne A. Price) once told me that any repetition operator on group was automatically suspect and often meant that the group should be replaced by an element.  She would, I guess, approve of your change.  But to make sense, the rationale for the change has to be greater ease of processing, not easier validation.

Answer (score 0):

One more:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/rules">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="if"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="if">
    <conditionSet>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="
                             following-sibling::*[not(self::if) 
                             and generate-id(preceding-sibling::if[1]) 
                                = generate-id(current())]
                             "/>
    </conditionSet>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I. Much simpler and shorter XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="elseif|else"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::if[1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <rules>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="if"/>
  </rules>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="if">
  <conditionSet>
   <xsl:copy-of select=".|key('kFollowing', generate-id())"/>
  </conditionSet>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<rules>
    <if condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="1"/>
    <elseif condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="2"/>
    <elseif condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="3"/>
    <else/>
    <if condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="4"/>
    <else/>
</rules>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<rules>
   <conditionSet>
      <if condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="1"/>
      <elseif condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="2"/>
      <elseif condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="3"/>
      <else/>
   </conditionSet>
   <conditionSet>
      <if condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="4"/>
      <else/>
   </conditionSet>
</rules>
```

---

**II. Even simpler and shorter XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <rules>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="if">
    <conditionSet>
     <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
    </conditionSet>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
  </rules>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
<rules>
   <conditionSet>
      <if condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="1"/>
      <elseif condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="2"/>
      <elseif condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="3"/>
      <else/>
   </conditionSet>
   <conditionSet>
      <if condition="equals" arg1="somevar" arg2="4"/>
      <else/>
   </conditionSet>
</rules>
```